# How to read in current process with here document

Tags: bash, syntax, heredoc, command-substitution

I would like to read in the current process:

```
mark=one
read a b c <<<$(grep "^$mark " <<EOF)
one    xxx yyy
two    zzz jjj
EOF

echo $b
```

But the heredoc is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Move `)` to a new line after closing `EOF`.